# x64dbg doesn't show Chinese strings in String references?

Tags: x64dbg

I'm wondering if x64dbg can show Chinese letters in String references? Because I try to reverse 3 Chinese programs from complete different coders and I never found any Chinese strings. But in the software there is obvious many Chinese texts.

Can someone tell me if x64Dbg can show Chinese strings and how to fix it?

Answer (score 1):

There is a plugin that enables x64dbg to support Chinese strings and searching for Chinese strings, it's called (x64dbg_tol).
After installing this plugin, you can search for Chinese strings that could not be found before.